# what is the code to Sync android phone with gmail contact

Tags: java, android

How do we Sync android phone with gmail contact?

Answer (score 0):

This is built into the OS, and is automatic. The user simply needs to enable it.

If the code isn't available as part of [the open source code for Android](http://source.android.com/), then it may be Google proprietary, in which case good luck getting the code.